# IIS 8 and authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating ASP.NET MVC 4 web application but when i launch it error 401.2 is occured.

web.config has following section:

```xml
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Then i added in web.config next lines:

```xml
<system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
</system.webServer>
```

After that i've got error 500.19

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have the windows authentication module installed?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 8 there are a few IIS security and .NET features that aren't enabled for IIS, when you just select an basic IIS installation.

If you'll be running in IIS proper locally you should also enable some of the Application Development Features too.

You'll need to go to 'Turn Windows Features on or off' and select a few of these:

[image: Windows features on off]